# How to disable ALL links' default click behaviour using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: The original error was a typo. I will rewrite it so it stays useful to the community.

How to disable all links with a certain class (e.g. ".disabled") from *linking* **without** adding a handler to **each** element?

The advantages of this approach is that it would work with every link (or element) with this class no matter if they were added dinamically or changed their classes during the life cycle of the webpage.

It is acceptable (for this use case) if the solution stops the "click" event from bubbling.

It is not acceptable (for this use case) to remove the href attribute, it might be "*not disabled*" later.

Comment: Your body one won't work because the handler for the `a` tags or any element you actually clicked on would propagate back up to the body. Not down from the body.

Comment: @ste2425 I dont understand your comment. Supposedly any click event in an element *bubbles* up to body unless stopped. I mean, the handler I wrote gets executed on click. But it opens the link afterwards nevertheless.

Comment: Your interpretation of the `$("a").on("click", ...)` isn't accurate. jQuery uses event delegation so you aren't getting one handler per link. Rather, you get one handler that can take care of all links.

Comment: *one handler per link? please.* Alas, as you realized, event delegation does not help at all in this case. Neutering the links individually seems like the only way to go.

Comment: @Josh that's exactly what I want. One handler that stops all links from executing.

Comment: Yes but the click event will first fire for the element clicked on. So the `<a>`. It would then bubble back up the tree to the body. See: https://jsfiddle.net/5n0979qb/

Comment: `$(".linkClass").click(function(ev){ev.preventDefault();});`  where `linkClass` is the class name for all links.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi are you positive about that? It sounds like a real pain to add-remove a handler every time I activate/deactivate a link. There HAS to be another way...

Comment: @next2u No, that's no use. Didn't you read the NOTE? What about dinamically loaded links or changes on their state? Even if I repeatedly execute that it would duplicate handlers in some cases.

Comment: `$('.disabled').each(function(i) { if ($(this).attr('href')) $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);'); });`

Comment: @Daniel, you don't *have* to add and remove the handler when an element changes state -- you can check that state (e.g. `hasClass("disabled")`) in the handler and only call `preventDefault()` when that check succeeds. You will, however, have to register a handler on all the elements you want to neuter that way.

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz, `$(document).on("click", ".linkClass", function(ev){ev.preventDefault();});` for dynamically created links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrxPXE)** with the debugging and listing all delegated events.

You can use jQuery's `.on()` method on the container, and you wont have the bulk of hundreds of click events.

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="container">  // #container has the event handler assigned
  <a>content</a>
  <a href="http://asdasd.com" class="disabled">Disabled</a>
  <a href="http://asdasd.com">Not disabled</a>
  <a>content</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Whenever <a> elements that descend from #container get   
// clicked the click event handler will fire.
$('#container').on( 'click','.disabled', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to attach an event to each element (this will do it):

```
$(".disabled").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I said I won't attach a handler to each element. If that means it can't be done, so be it. I'd even accept that as an answer

Comment: It's only every '.disabled' element. But yes, it has to be done like this. Otherwise you can just add a `if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled'))` condition to all your click handlers.

Comment: Don't particularly see a need to stopPropagation(), just to preventDefault(). An ancestor on the page at some point in time might want to know something was clicked.

Comment: preventDefault will stop link href actions. stopPropagation will stop other click handlers

Comment: Yes, but in this case the other click handlers are triggered using event delegation on ancestors

Answer (score 1):

Apply following class to all a elements:

```
.not-active{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

$('a').addClass('not-active');
```

Comment: Note that `pointer-events: none` is only supported from IE11 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="body">
  <a href="javascript:alert('Click');">Enabled</a>
  <a href="javascript:alert('Click');" class="disabled">Disabled</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".body").on('click','a',function(e){
    if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      alert("Click disabled");
    }
  });
 </script>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Oh, I had these. But it might as well only work in Chrome & Firefox

Comment: This will disable the href links but not other click events

Comment: I was gonna ask "how is this different from my initial approach?" when I realized... it is not. I HAD A TYPO U_U *shaaame*

Comment: btw, body doesn't have a ".". It is not a class. Also, you can just do $("body").on("click","a.disabled", function (e){});

Comment: I used `.body` to make the example work. For real live use, replace `.body` with `body` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable for redirect on linked url by this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<br />
<a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('body').click(function () {return false;});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">  // #container has the event handler assigned
  <a>content</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">Disabled</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Not disabled</a>
  <a>content</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#container').on( 'click','.disabled', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace the href links with void reference:

```
$('.disabled').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr('href')) $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
});
```

As a followup measure, in case you still need the actual links, you could save them to the object's data, then change them!

```
$('.disabled').each(function(i) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href) {
        $(this).data('href', href)
            .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
    }
});
```

**Example**

```js
$('.disabled').each(function(i) {
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
 if (href) {
  $(this).data('href', href)
   .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
 }
});

setTimeout(function() {
 $('.disabled').each(function(i) {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (href) {
   var href = $(this).data('href');
   console.log(href)
   $(this).after($('<i />', { html: ' &nbsp; - My old Link was: <b>' + href + '<b />' }).fadeIn());
  }
 });
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="bob.com" class="disabled">bob</a><br />
<p class="disabled">ron</p><br />
<a href="jane.com" class="disabled">jane</a><br />
<h3 class="disabled">sally</h3><br />
<a href="trump.com" class="disabled">trump</a><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not a valid solution for this example, as stated in the question, because a)creates a handler for **every** link , b) it is not dynamic, c) you lose the link forever. C was not specified in the question, though.